# Iterators and templates in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following hierarchy. A file is:

```
vector<Dataset<here lies the problem!!!>>
```

then I want each Dataset to be:

```
vector<Record>
```

but Record is a template type, that is you create a Dataset like this:

```
Dataset<Record> dataset;
```

I need to be able to iterate over datasets, then for each dataset
to iterate over records, but I can't because each Dataset has its own
different Record, so basically each Dataset is a different type,
and I can't have different types in a vector.

More clarification:

Dataset is a CSV dataset, by which I mean more CSV lines.
A Record is basically one CSV line, but represented
by a user-specified struct.

And it is not that much about iteration, as it is also about storage. We might have something like 20 Datasets, and we want to store them in one structure like a vector or something. So it is not just about iteration.

Comment: You need to provide more context. How are `Dataset` and `Record` related? How are they declared?

Comment: I added clarification :)

Comment: Clarify more about your concrete code for `Record` and `Dataset`!! (Ah, you again ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are of different types, iterating over them doesn't make sense; what code would run on every type of Dataset?

Once you find an answer to this question, abstract that information and either use as an interface and make Datasets inherit from it or use some TMP type erasure.

#### To give you an example:

```
class Apple { ... };
class Pear { ... };

vector<SomeTypeThatCanHoldApplesAndPears> v;
for (x : v) {
    // what do you want to do with x?
}
```

And an example thing that fullfils that:

```
// They are both fruits and have a color!
class Fruit { public: virtual Color getColor() = 0; }
class Apple : public Fruit { /* implement getColor */ };
class Pear : public Fruit { /* implement getColor */ };
```

Now only use a `vector` of a pointer of reference wrapper type or type erasure that can hold `Fruit`s:

```
for (fruit : v) {
    fruit.getColor();
}
```

#### More advanced solution

You can use `Boost.TypeErasure` and [create a concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/concept.html#boost_typeerasure.concept.custom) that will have the behavior you want.

Comment: Actually we really need to be able to iterate over datasets, and then over the records in the dataset.

Comment: That doesn't change a thing in what you need to do.

Comment: And it is not that much about iteration, as it is about storage. We might have something like 20 Datasets, and we want to store them in one structure like a vector or something. So it is not just about iteration.

Comment: Storing them in one container only makes sense if they support some kind of operation that can be done over all of them. If there's no such case, you'll gain nothing by storing them in one container. You would need to inspect type in runtime either by RTTI or some homegrown raw memory access, and it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
template <typename R>
struct DataSet
{
  typedef R record_type; 
};    

int main()
{
  std::vector<boost::variant<DataSet<int>, DataSet<std::string>>> datasets;
}
```

see here for more info http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: Since it's a "user-specified struct", `variant` isn't a very good fit because you don't know the types beforehand. Otherwise of course, use it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz "We might have something like 20 Datasets" <- seemed like the types were known